# how to read data from file in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data in file in following format..

```
{"name":1, "children": [2,3,4,5,6]}
{"name":2, "children": [12,13,54,25,16]}
{"name":3, "children": [22,34,43,25,26]}
```

Basically I am trying to get visualization like this:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

But rather than loading json directly.. I want to look it up from this file..
So, something like: `{"name":1, "children": [2,3,4,5,6]}`
and then i click on 2.. then it reads the children of node 2 and populates the graph further?

So basically, rather than loading the complete json.. I want to make it interactable that user can just click on node and then i look it up and populate it further.
How do i do this.
I am not much of an expert in js :(

Comment: Do you mean that you have the data already parsed and in soem array in the code? If that is the case you should be able to just modify the toggle function of the example you posted to look up the correct information to add. You will have to recursively add the children though since the layout uses a nested structure and it looks like your data is an adjacency list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to load the data you can use JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Otherwise, you can use d3's json function to load the data, but then only show a particular branch (with e.g. filtering)

If your problem is that the json file is too big to load in memory, then you can do it manually by reading the file with HTML 5's FileReader, and then pass the selected chunk to d3.